# Passing a updating parameter to

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have an application that is mostly Razor Pages and tried out integrating some Blazor components. My Blazor component has a child component and I'm trying to get it to display data from one of the parent's parameters but the data is coming up null even through I specify it before I call a method on the child.

Having a tough time grasping how to make the child get the updated value of the AppException parameter. I tried wrapping the ErrorModal component in `<CascadingValue Value=@AppException></CascadingValue>`

Seems to me AppException parameter is null when the child component is rendered and it stays that way regardless if I change it before calling a method on the child.

Running Blazor asp.net core 6

**RazorPageWithBlazorComponent.cshtml:**

```
<component type="typeof(MyBlazorComponent)" render-mode="Server" />
```

**MyBlazorComponent.razor:**

```
@code {

    private Exception AppException { get; set; }

    public void ThrowSampleError(){
        try {
            throw new Exception("I crashed");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            AppException = ex;
            MyModal.Open(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**MyModal.razor:**

```
<div class="modal @ModalClass">modal content</div>
@code {
   
    [Parameter]
    public Exception AppException { get; set; }
    public string ModalClass = "";

    public void Open()
    {
        // Next line throws an error because AppException is null
        NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        _logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, AppException.Message + " ---- " + AppException.StackTrace);
        ModalClass = "Show";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception will not inherently be null when passing from a component to another, you can follow my sample. Pay attention that StateHasChanged() should be set in MyBlazorComponent.razor, and you don’t need to call the method in parent component.

> RazorPageWithBlazorComponent.cshtml:

```
<component type="typeof(MyBlazorComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
<component type="typeof(MyModal)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

> MyModal.razor

```
@* Call the open method when rendering *@
@if (_appException != null)
{
    Open();
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Error:</strong> @_appException.Message
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Exception _appException { get; set; }

    public void Open()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_appException);
    }
}
```

> MyBlazorComponent.razor:

```
<h3>MyBlazorComponent</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ThrowSampleError">Click me</button>

<MyModal _appException="@AppException" />  //ChildComponent to pass the value when rendering

@code {

    public Exception AppException { get; set; }

    public void ThrowSampleError()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("I crashed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppException = ex;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Test

[image]

And the exception is passed

[image]